# Non relational database for twisted

Tags: python, database, twisted, non-relational-database

I'm looking for any key-value database implementation for working with twisted in asynchronous mode. 
The one Idea that I have is using the Twisted Memcache API with MemcacheDB.

Is this some other solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of possible solution is using [Redis](http://redis.io/)(REmote DIctionary Server). 
Redis is very fast, powerful and stable key-value storage which is used in [many projects](http://redis.io/topics/whos-using-redis). Stackoverflow also uses redis;).

I've recently start using redis in my current project for creating user's ratings. My personal opinion: redis is very simple, very fast and stable. It also has a pretty command line client, I like it.

On website I use synchronous `redis` [package](https://github.com/andymccurdy/redis-py). Server uses twisted and requires asynchronous approach. Fortunately, there is third-party module [txredis](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/txredis/), which allows easily to interact with redis database using twisted. I didn't have any problems with it. However, `txredis` doesn't have a connection pool, but it's not a problem to implement it manually, if needed.

Comment: Perhaps you should contribute a connection pool back to the txredis project? :)

Comment: Curious why you would want to use a connection pool with Redis. txRedis is designed to use a persistent connection to a single Redis instance. Since Redis itself is an asynchronous server, I fail to see why having a pool of connections from one instance to a single Redis server would help. The only case where this makes sense is if all request goes through some sort of proxy service. Is that what your application does?

Answer (score 1):

I use Apache Cassandra from twisted, using [Telephus](https://github.com/driftx/Telephus) if production for years.

Comment: checked out Telephus but can't seem to get sufficient examples to start with. Can you give an example of CRUD operations using Telephus?

Answer (score -1):

Adding one more point to @dr. 's answer marked as accepted : Use the python package [txredisapi](https://github.com/fiorix/txredisapi), which uses [redis protocol for twisted](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/txredis/2.3) with connection pool support and many more.